# How to update the .po and .pot files in gettext module using python

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext

I created language translate using get text module, now i added more strings in my file i run this program earlier strings are converting and remaning strings are not translated.can any one please tell me how can i update the .pot, .po and .mo files using get text module in Linux

[image]

Comment: "please provide me any reference links"—sorry, that's not how Stack Overflow works. The [help/on-topic] says "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Please read [ask] as well.

Comment: You can reduce it to a [mcve]. We don't need all of your code, we just need a representative example.

Comment: How is your pushbutton code related to translating?

Answer (score 5):

> how can i update the .pot, .po and .mo files using get text module in
>   Linux?

Generate POT files from Python code using `xgettext`:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html#xgettext-Invocation

Update existing PO files from new POT files using `msgmerge`:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgmerge-Invocation.html#msgmerge-Invocation

Compile PO files into MO files using `msgfmt`:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgfmt-Invocation.html#msgfmt-Invocation

Comment: You can also read the linked content by showing the manuals of xgettext and msmerge from the command line if your system has GNU Internationalization utilities (aka *gettext*) installed, so the linked content would still exist even if the links became obsolete.